# External ID not searchable in Global Search

Tags: externalid, global-search

We have a custom object (allow search = true) with a tab default on in a sandbox where there is an External ID field on which we'd like to perform search.

When searching on it, nothing is displayed but when I refine the search by this particular object, we find the associated records.

The expected behavior would be not to have to refine the search for the user to quickly find them (operation happening a lot of times in the day to day of a user).

I'm stuck regarding solutions on this and would like some help.

Thanks in advance,
Gauthier

Comment: did you add this field to the search layout?

Comment: Yes is has been added to the Default Search Layout which is assigned to all profiles

Comment: Please refer the link here about the search results - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_find_objects_fields.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

As per [Searchable Fields by Object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_lex.htm&type=5), all the external Id fields are searchable. Whenever you search for a keyword, it fetches all matching records(probably your object is not listed on top search list, but if that value is available in only that object then that object should come up in search result) and we need to drill down by selecting the specific object.

If you want to save time in filtering Object specific search, can build a quick component using flow to give you a small screen to just enter the keyword and based on that show the results on that screen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The wierd behavior comes from the fact that nothing is returned. When I read you, it seems that the expected behavior would be to have my records listed without a drilldown.

Is there anything I can do to list my object in top search results?

I want to avoid a custom search on top of the global search.

Comment: Hope in that Object settings "Allow Search" is enabled(you are saying it is coming after drill so it should have been enabled) but pls do check it
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330207&type=1

Comment: Indeed "Allow Search" is enabled. What I want is to have my results in Top Search as I am searching on an External ID (indexed) field and not to have to drilldown to the object.